# output of command in string interpolation in bash

Tags: bash

How can I echo the node location like this:

```
echo "node can be found at the following location ${which node}"
```

This results in a bad substitution error.

Comment: Use `echo "node can be found at the following location $(which note)"`

Comment: `${}` is called [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). What you need is [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) (`$()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
echo "node can be found at the following location $(which node)"
```

`$()` is a subshell you could read more about it in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442704/53084):